# Getting http.handleFunc() to work on gRPC server

Tags: go

So I'm trying to get a small gRPC app running in GOlang. The gPRC commands work fine, however, I also want to be able to interact with my database from the URL. Before I added the gRPC server, it worked fine, but after either the gRPC server or the "normal" server got blocked and wouldn't be able to start up. Is there a way to both have a gRPC interface and be able to make call from the URL?

My server code:

```
func main(){
    createItem("test", "test")
    http.HandleFunc("/get/", get)
    http.HandleFunc("/set/", set)
    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":4000")
    if err != nil{
        log.Fatal("Listener error: ", err)
    }
    s := grpc.NewServer()
    pb.RegisterGetSetServiceServer(s, &server{})
    reflection.Register(s)
    s.Serve(listener)


    log.Printf("serving rpc on port %d", 4000)
    err = http.Serve(listener, nil)
    if err != nil{
        log.Fatal("error serving: ", err)
    }

}

func (s *server) Get(ctx Context, req *pb.GetRequest) (*pb.Response, error) {
    var body string
    log.Printf("Recived: %v", req.GetTitle())
    for _, val := range database{
        if req.GetTitle() == val.Title{
            body = val.Body
            return &pb.Response{Body:body}, nil
        }
    }
    return &pb.Response{Body:"Nothing found"}, nil

}
func get(writer http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request ){
    var value string


    v := req.FormValue("key")
    for _, val := range database{
        if val.Title == v {
              value = val.Body
        }
    }
    fmt.Fprintln(writer,  value)
}
```

Comment: grpc Server has Serve(..) and [ServeHTTP(..)](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc#Server.ServeHTTP) to serve one port for both grpc and http2 requests

Answer (score 1):

As Mark said in the comment, you can serve gRPC inside a Go HTTP server.  The documentation for `ServeHTTP` has an explanation:

https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc#Server.ServeHTTP

However, this isn't recommended or supported by the gRPC-Go team, as it doesn't allow some gRPC features to work (e.g. Keepalives).  Instead we recommend either using different ports, or using something like `cmux` so that you can run the full gRPC server in addition to a separate HTTP server:

https://github.com/soheilhy/cmux